# Why the operation hierarchy works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know if this is a silly question, but they never teached me this at school, i will have to trust my teacher and not doubt about this affirmation, but why we are completly sure that performing simple arithmetic operations in an specific order gives a correct answer?

*For example:*

2 + 4 × 2

- Why we completly affirm that this is 10 and not 12?
- Why this hierarchy is difined like this?
- Why this works?

Comment: If they did not teach this in school, then your teacher is as dumb as the football coach who taught science class when I was in school back in the '60s. You always resolve 1) parentheses 2) powers and factorials 3) multiplication and division 4) addition and subtraction in that order so $2+4\times 2=10$

Comment: I mean, that they've never teached me why this hierarchy works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mere convention ... so it could've historically ended up differently, but it hasn't, we are where we are, it's been accepted by everyone, and so everyone needs to learn it.

If you write something like:

$$2+4\times 2$$

(or, let's make it worse:

$$2+2\times 2-2-(2^{2+2^2}+2):2+2+2\times 2:2$$

) ... what does this writing even *mean*? The convention is about deciding what it means, i.e. which operations will be done first, and which will follow. Over centuries, people settled with the following:

- **Brackets (Parentheses)**: Do those first. Whatever is in brackets needs to be calculated already (as a separate, standalone, expression), before you go forward.
- **Indices (Exponents)**: Calculate those next, right-to-left. If you have something like $2^2$ do it here. If you have something like $2^{3^4}$ you do $3^4(=81)$ first, then you do $2^{81}$
- **Division/Multiplication**: Do both, from left to right, in the order they appear.
- **Addition/Subtraction**: Do both of them, again, from left to right, in the order they appear.

Those rules are usually remembered using a mnemonic BIDMAS or PEDMAS (or PEMDAS).

The flipside is, if you want the operations in your expression to be done in a *different* order than prescribed, you then put brackets/parentheses to modify the order.

In your question: $2+4\times 2$, there are no parentheses and no indices, but we do the multiplication first ($4\times 2 = 8$), and then we do addition ($2+8=10$). If you *want* it to be calculated differently, i.e. to first add $2+4$, and *then* multiply by $2$, you put $2+4$ in brackets, i.e. the expression becomes: $(2+4)\times 2$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some simple calculators, though, have no knowledge of this, and if you type $2+4\times 2$ into them, they will show $12$. They follow a different convention, which may be confusing. Most modern calculators, however, "know" about BIDMAS/PEDMAS and do what is expected. There are also other conventions used for various special purposes, such as RPN (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), in which $2+4\times 2$ would be written as $2\space 4\space 2\space \times\space +$. Mentioning just FYI, no need to remember it.

Comment: The thing is, why this convention works, why the things you write down on a paper, in theory, then works on real life.

Comment: *Any* convention would work. We just needs a way to write succinctly something that would be in words "multiply $4$ by $2$ and add that to $2$" - many centuries ago people actually did this all in words! This has nothing to do with "real world". As far as the real world is concerned, some real things follow mathematical patterns (so science and engineering works, right?), and it is an interesting question in itself. However, we are here concerned only about *writing down* the mathematical patterns, once we have identified them already. This is not the same question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo (Cont'd) You can just as easily ask why it works to write $\times$ (two crossed lines) for multiplication ... It does not matter, this is just another convention, and some people write $\cdot$ or $\circ$... Or it works when we write numbers as $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ (again, we could write them as $I, II, III, IV, V\ldots$ - that would be another convention). In other words, there is nothing mathematical in the convention, it is part of language, but it is the language that you can *use* to express mathematical ideas.